# removing class from element when the class goes to another one in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

first sorry if you don't understand the title

I have a list that contains elements
once I click on an item, "s" class must be added to it and removed from others
I try to remove by loop but didn't work

```js
function selectIt(x) {
  x.classList.add('s');
  var items = document.querySelectorAll('item');
  for (i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    items[i].classList.remove('s');
  }
}
```

```css
.s {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="list">
  <div class="item" onclick="selectIt(this)">item 1</div>
  <div class="item s" onclick="selectIt(this)">item 2</div>
  <div class="item" onclick="selectIt(this)">item 3</div>
  <div class="item" onclick="selectIt(this)">item 4</div>
  <div class="item" onclick="selectIt(this)">item 5</div>
</div>
```

Comment: put your `x.classList.add('s');` after your for loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not defining the type of selector in `querySelectorAll` like you want to search for a class or id.
Add the `s` class at the end and not in the beginning, as defining it in the start will remove the `s` class from the current element also.

Also, you can search for `s` class in the querySelector instead of searching for item.

```js
function selectIt(x) {
  var items = document.querySelectorAll('.s');
  for (i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    items[i].classList.remove('s');
  }
  x.classList.add('s');
}
```

```css
.s {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="list">
  <div class="item" onclick="selectIt(this)">item 1</div>
  <div class="item s" onclick="selectIt(this)">item 2</div>
  <div class="item" onclick="selectIt(this)">item 3</div>
  <div class="item" onclick="selectIt(this)">item 4</div>
  <div class="item" onclick="selectIt(this)">item 5</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to run a loop at all. First, remove the class `s` from the previous `div` element and add it to the new `div` element which is clicked.

```js
function selectIt(x) {
  let item = document.querySelector('.s');
  item.classList.remove('s')
  x.classList.add('s');
}
```

```css
.s {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="list">
  <div class="item" onclick="selectIt(this)">item 1</div>
  <div class="item s" onclick="selectIt(this)">item 2</div>
  <div class="item" onclick="selectIt(this)">item 3</div>
  <div class="item" onclick="selectIt(this)">item 4</div>
  <div class="item" onclick="selectIt(this)">item 5</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this like this

```js
function selectIt(x) {
            var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('item');
            for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
                elements[i].style.backgroundColor = 'white';
            }
            x.style.backgroundColor = "red"
        }
```

```html
<div class="list">
        <div class="item" onclick="selectIt(this)">item 1</div>
        <div class="item" onclick="selectIt(this)">item 2</div>
        <div class="item" onclick="selectIt(this)">item 3</div>
        <div class="item" onclick="selectIt(this)">item 4</div>
        <div class="item" onclick="selectIt(this)">item 5</div>
    </div>
```

Basically first i have made background color of class item = white
then i have made background of "this" red